# Sort a collection alphanumerically in backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, natural-sort

I have written a comparator to sort the collection based on "id" like this:

```
comparator: function(coll) {
    return coll.get('id');
}
```

This works fine for input: "id-1, id-0, id-2, id-199" to sort as "id-0, id-1, id-2, id-199"

But does not sort numerically here: "id-1, id-0, id-2, id-199, id-99" as "id-0, id-1, id-2, id-199, id-99" -- id-99 should be before id-199.

Comment: try `coll.get('id').replace("id-","") | 0`

Comment: That could work, but the initial string "id-" is not constant.

Comment: `coll.get('id').replace(/[^0-9^\.]/g,"")|0`

Comment: Thank you @suish - that works, can you explain the "| 0" part?

Comment: It's probably not needed though,`| 0` is Bitwise operation which does nothing at all. but javascript bitwise operate does converting into 32bit number before start calculating so it end up meaning the same as "parseInt".(bit faster than parseInt)

Comment: I tried to remove it and it stopped working. Looks like javascript does need this to sort the numerical part of the name correctly.

Comment: which means it can only handle Number but String Number

Comment: @suish I am now trying to do this with locale comparison, so passing in two models:  

    comparator: function(model1, model) {
        if ((model1.get('id').localeCompare(model2.get('id'))) < 0) {
            return -1;
    }
    if ((model1.get('id').localeCompare(model2.get('id'))) > 0) {
     return 1;
    }

Fixated on how to get the alphanumeric part in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

As commented by @suish the way this was solved was by performing a replace of all non-numerical part with empty string.

```
coll.get('id').replace(/[^0-9^\.]/g,"")|0 –
```

Comment: please update the answer with the solution from comments and accept it to indicate that the problem is solved.

Comment: But you said that *the initial string "id-" is not constant* so how could throwing the prefix away properly sort things?

Comment: @muistooshort - Because we used a regular expression instead: /[^0-9^\.]/g

Comment: So you don't care about the prefix when sorting?

Comment: @muistooshort - /[^0-9^\.]/g covers the strings with numbers and/or letters.

Comment: And `replace(/[^0-9^\.]/g,"")` removes such things so apparently you don't care about the prefix so `'x-11'` and `'pancakes-11'` should sort the same.

Comment: That's correct, it could be any alphanumeric string. pancakes-11 will be ordered before x-11. But pancakes-101 will be sorted between pancakes-11 and x-11. Hope that makes sense. @muistooshort