# Passing 2 models versus one model to backbone comparator and doing alphanumeric sort

Tags: javascript, sorting, backbone.js

New to backbone, I am trying to sort a collection alphanumerically, and doing it with one model passed in like below works fine:

```
comparator: function(model) {
    return model.get('id').replace(/[^0-9^\.]/g,"")|0;
}
```

Here is my previous question and resolution:
[Sort a collection alphanumerically in backbone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33621926/sort-a-collection-alphanumerically-in-backbone?noredirect=1#comment55019531_33621926)

Now if I do something like to get in a locale comparison:

```
comparator: function(model1, model2) {
    if ((model1.get('id').localeCompare(model2.get('id'))) < 0)
        return -1;
    }
    if ((model1.get('id').localeCompare(model2.get('id'))) >0) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This works fine for input: "id-1, id-0, id-2, id-199" to sort as "id-0, id-1, id-2, id-199"

But does not sort numerically here: "id-1, id-0, id-2, id-199, id-99" as "id-0, id-1, id-2, id-199, id-99" -- id-99 should be before id-199. Obviously because the numerical comparison is not incorporated. I haven;t been able to successfully implement that, any ideas?

Comment: That's invalid javascript code.parentheses are not used properly.it should be `if (model1.get('id').localeCompare(model2.get('id')) < 0)` and the latter if sentence has a same issue too.

Comment: @suish - my apologies, I had written the code and relied on my abilities to match the parentheses at almost midnight. I think I have corrected it now.

Answer (score 1):

`localeCompare` simply compare each characters one by one. so it does not recognize the number part as a number but separate single numbers like 1,9,9.
so You need to write own comparator for the number part.

try this code blow(I haven't even tested the code so it could have typo or some syntax error)

```
comparator: function(model1, model2) {
  var m1num = model1.get("id").replace(/[^0-9^\.]/g,"")|0 || 0
  var m1str = model1.get("id").replace(m1num,"")
  var m2num = model2.get("id").replace(/[^0-9^\.]/g,"")|0 || 0
  var m2str = model2.get("id").replace(m2num,"")
  switch(true){
    case m1str.localeCompare(m2str) < 0:
      return -1;
    case m1str.localeCompare(m2str) > 0:
      return 1;
    case m1str.localeCompare(m2str) == 0:
      if(m1num < m2num) return 1
      else if(m1num > m2num) return -1
      else return 0
  }
}
```

FYI, this code above does not work properly if your model ids are something like "i8d-99" and "i7d-200". because the function end up comparing 899 and 7200. but other than that, it should work how you expect

Comment: thanks, this makes sense when I read it. I was reaching to a similar conclusion after reading some posts as well. Check the last post's SortCustom function at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9431171/correctly-implement-backbone-comparators

I will try this.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @suish, the solution on those lines (with some minor fixes I had to do is):

```
comparator: function(model1, model2) {
  var m1num = model1.get("id").replace(/[^0-9^\.]/g,"")|0 || 0
  var m1str = model1.get("id").replace(/[0-9]/g,"")
  var m2num = model2.get("id").replace(/[^0-9^\.]/g,"")|0 || 0
  var m2str = model2.get("id").replace(/[0-9]/g,"")
  switch(true){
    case m1str.localeCompare(m2str) < 0:
      return -1;
    case m1str.localeCompare(m2str) > 0:
      return 1;
    case m1str.localeCompare(m2str) == 0:
      if(m1num < m2num) return -1
      else if(m1num > m2num) return 1
      else return 0
  }
}
```